Why is a single disk failure per mirror enough to take out a RAID 01 array?
I have learned that RAID 10 is a stripe of mirrors, while RAID 01 is a mirror of stripes.

Now, I have frequently read that the primary difference between RAID 10 and RAID 01 is that RAID 10 provides higher fault-tolerance. The justification for this claim was that in RAID 10, every disk in a single mirror must fail in order for the array to fail, while in RAID 01, one disk failure per stripe is enough to take the array down.
However, I challenge the latter claim. While I fully understand why one disk failure is enough to take down a single RAID 0 array, I don't understand why a single disk failure per stripe necessarily takes out a mirror of RAID 0 arrays. Consider the RAID 01 array shown above, and say that Disk 0 and Disk 3 fail. In this case, hasn't no data loss occurred (as all blocks are still stored in the array by Disk 1 and Disk 2)? In that case, why is it claimed that a single disk failure per stripe is enough to take out a RAID 01 array?

The answers you linked to indicates you can lose one disk in either configuration.  As for the reason, it's the difference, if RAID 1 and RAID 0 is "ontop of the array" or not. RAID 0 has not redundancy. So if you lose a disk with RAID 10, you are left with a RAID, without any redundancy.

I think the issue is that you are considering whether all your data is somewhere, which as you point out, it is, but the concern here is the state of the Array's logical volume rather than whether a particular physical disk has still has your data. I don't think there is any case where Raid0 doesn't hurt reliability. It is for optimizing disk operations, rather than for reliability/redundancy. Since a Raid0 cannot be rebuilt, just having the data somewhere won't help you; it has to be in a place where it allows the array to be rebuilt.

In your example, in RAID 0+1 disks 0 and 1 form a single logical disk A, which is a RAID 0 disk, and disks 1 and 2 form a single logical disk B, which is also a RAID 0 disk. Then the whole disk A is mirrored to disk B, producing a single logical disk C which is a RAID 1 disk. If disk 0 fails, the whole disk A fails, because that's how RAID 0 works. It doesn't matter that disk 1 is still functional. Similarly, if disk 3 fails, the whole disk B fails and it doesn't matter that disk 2 is still functional. So both disks A and B fail and the entire mirror C fails.
Please consider that RAID 0+1 setup does not guarantee that data on disks 0 and 2 are identical, or data on disks 1 and 3 are identical. The picture is a bit misleading. It only guarantees that data on disks A and B are identical, but they may be laid out differently between "sub-disks" in each of the disks A and B (think for example about the case when disk A is built of three 200 GB drives forming a 600 GB RAID 0 disk, and disk B is built of two 300 GB drives also forming a 600 GB RAID 0 disk - it is totally possible!). So you cannot rely on an assumption that if disk 0 fails, the same data is still available on disk 2.
In RAID 1+0, disks 0 and 1 form a single RAID 1 disk A, and disks 2 and 3 form a single RAID 1 disk B. Disks A and B are then joined into RAID 0 disk C. If disk 0 fails, disk A is still operable, thanks to the mirror on disk 1. If disk 3 fails, disk B is still operable thanks to mirror on disk 2. So the entire disk C still works.
If one more disk fails, either disk A or disk B will become inoperable, which will take down the entire disk C.
